# Kinect sensor gazebo-ros

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to add a kinect sensor to a simulation I have already running using a hokuyo laser as sensor for navigation. I want to add the kinect sensor in order to simulate navigation using point clouds. I have all of this already running in the real robot.

I am using ros groovy and Gazebo 1.6

The important part of the .sdf I use is at the end of the question. I have gone through the tutorials but I am still not sure about how sensors and plugins properly work. For what I understand just adding the camera depth sensor should get the topic from gazebo listed in a gztopic list, but I do not see this happening. And for what I understand adding the plugin besides adding new functionalities should make the bridge to ros available so that it would publish in the same topics as a depth camera does in ros.

I am pretty stuck so I would appreciate any help.

Thanks for our time.

```
<link name="kinect::link">
    <pose>0.2 0 0.265 0 0 0</pose>
    <inertial>
    <mass>0.1</mass>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
            <box>
            <size>0.073000 0.276000 0.072000</size>
            </box>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
            <mesh>
                <uri>model://kinect/meshes/kinect.dae</uri>
            </mesh>
        </geometry>
    </visual>

  <sensor name="camera" type="depth">
    <pose>0.2 0 0.265 0 0 0</pose>
    <update_rate>20</update_rate>
    <camera>
      <horizontal_fov>1.047198</horizontal_fov>
      <image>
        <width>640</width>
        <height>480</height>
        <format>R8G8B8</format>
      </image>
      <clip>
        <near>0.05</near>
        <far>3</far>
      </clip>
    </camera>
    <plugin name="camera" filename='libDepthCameraPlugin.so'>
        <alwaysOn>1</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
    <image_topic_name>image_raw</image_topic_name>
        <point_cloud_topic_name>points</point_cloud_topic_name>
     <camera_info_topic_name>camera_info</camera_info_topic_name>
    <cameraName>depth_cam</cameraName>
        <frameName>/base_link</frameName>
        <point_cloud_cutoff>0.001</point_cloud_cutoff>
    <distortionK1>0.00000001</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.00000001</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.00000001</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.00000001</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.00000001</distortionT2>
  </sensor>
</link>
 
  <joint name="kinect_joint" type="revolute">
    <child>kinect::link</child>
    <parent>chassis</parent>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
      <limit>
        <upper>0</upper>
        <lower>0</lower>
      </limit>
    </axis>
  </joint>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3296/kinect-sensor-gazebo-ros/) by [agonzamart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/250/agonzamart/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `<alwaysOn>` should be a child of `<sensor>`, not `<plugin>`. This should force the sensor to be on all the time, and you should see a gztopic.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/250/agonzamart/) on 2013-06-30**:
Thanks I had already solved it but I didn't know exactly what had made it work. I appreciate it! :)

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/250/agonzamart/) on 2013-07-04**:
nkoening I was checking out the config I used for the .sdf to make the kinect work and I realized I did't use the  tag at all. But I still get ros topics published. I can add a image viewer to rviz and I see the image from the simulated camera /depth_cam/depth/image_raw. I even used a cloudthrottle to make a laserscan and seems to work properly. But if I try to add the  tag as a child of sensor I get an error from the .sdf parser

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/250/agonzamart/) on 2013-07-04**:
Error [parser.cc:719] XML Element[alwaysOn], child of element[sensor] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[sensor]
Error [parser.cc:710] Error reading element 
Error [parser.cc:710] Error reading element 
Error [parser.cc:710] Error reading element 
Error [parser.cc:710] Error reading element 
Error [parser.cc:369] Unable to read element 
Error [Server.cc:253] Unable to read sdf file

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/250/agonzamart/) on 2013-07-04**:
I also see here: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins in the Skid Steering Drive paragraph for example that the  tag is used inside the plugin, I see no difference between using the tag inside the plugin or not using it so I assume that it is not being used. On the other hand when I use a gztopic I can not see wich one is from the camera, but gazebo must be publishing this topic if I can read it trough the ros topic. I think I might not getting something

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/250/agonzamart/) on 2013-07-04**:
I really appreciate your help and time